# how to register for a new channel uri with the MPNS?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

How do i get a new channel uri from MPNS ? Its returning the same one from the last few calls.And if I use it , it returns 404 error.So I want to get a new channelUri to test the push notification.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you only can register ONE push channel for Application, and registered URL remains the same until MS decide to change it.

However, system seems a little buggy. For example, you use

```
var pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(K_PushChannelName);
```

to obtain your channel, sometimes it returns null, but when trying to create a new one with a call to Open() you get an exception or gets an empty URI.

This can happen by a lot of reasons. You have used all 500 push notifications/day without certificate, you have another push channel open in the app, or it is a simply Microsoft server fail.

One workaround for some errors is to delete application from phone/emulator and re-install it.

I've experienced a lot of problems with push channels, until have to wait 24/48 hours to continue developing. However, when in production all seems being working ok. It seems happens only when you do a lot of calls to channel search/open.